# VBA - make range include empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that grabs the values under the headers HOLDER and CUTTING TOOL, gets the last row taken up in that column, and prints the information to a master sheet.

It works well; however, I now realize that some of the cells under HOLDER and/or CUTTING TOOL can be blank. The easiest fix would be to set up another find for the header TOOL NUM in column A of my opened file, get the last row in that column, and make sure that if there is a value in the TOOL NUM column, but no value under HOLDER or CUTTING TOOL, that a blank cell is copied over.

Something alone the lines of... (**outline of code**)

```
for occupied cells in TOOL NUM, 
if holder has value
    print 
else 
    print blank cell
if cutting tool has value
    print
else
    print blank cell
```

I have done something similar in section (5) with the TDS name getting the last row in the column of the masterfile column "C" and printing down to that last value.

I do not know how to put this idea into working code without completely wrecking my current code. Any ideas?

**FULL CODE:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, d As Range
    Dim TDS As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("A1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2


    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO 'CUTTING TOOL' PRESENT!"
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    'If InStr(ROW_HEADER, "HOLDER") <> "" Then
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

                        'Set d = StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(WB, "A"), 1)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    'Else
                        'StartSht.Cells(Rows.Count, hc1.Column.End
                    End If
                    'End If
                Else
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO 'CUTTING TOOL' PRESENT!"
                End If
'(5)
            With WB
                    'print the file name to Column 4
                    StartSht.Cells(i, 4) = objFile.Name

                    With ws
                    'Print TDS name by searching for header
                        If Not Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                            Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
                        Else
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO TDS VALUE!"
                        End If
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                    End With
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
'(7)
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'brings the viewer to the top of the masterfile
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim v
    Dim spl As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ";")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ",")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Comment: It looks like for both "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL" you use the `GetValues` function to get a dictionary of the values underneath those headings. Can you not change the function so it includes an entry if blank cells exist?

Comment: Great idea! I'll work on that. I'm not incredibly familiar with vba so if you could help me with one quick question that'd be great. Right now for the GetValues section I have `If Len(v) > 0 Then`. To get empty files would I just throw an `Else` statement or `If Len(v) = 0` ? What do you think would work best @ChipsLetten ?

Comment: I's out of the first loop but there is an `If Len(v) = 0` statement

Answer (score 0):

Change the `GetValues` function so adds an empty string value into the dictionary. Change the `If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then ... End If` statement to this:

```
    If Not dict.exists(v) Then
        If Len(v) > 0 Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                spl = Split(v, ";")
                v = spl(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
                spl = Split(v, ",")
                v = spl(0)
            End If
        End If
        dict.Add c.Address, v
    End If
```

You will need to check if an empty cell will mess up any other of the code.

Comment: Is the change the `GetValues` function to add an empty string value into the dictionary tip part of the code you change or separate? If it's separate, how would I go about changing that? Because after that section that you typed I have `If Len(v) = 0` `Then v = "none"` and I thought that covered it. @ChipsLetten